# Change material projection method?

Tags: texturing

I'm new to Blender (coming from Cinema 4D) and wondering how I change the material projection method? Also, I'm wondering how to tile a material on a specific mesh?

[image]

*In C4D, if I click on the "Texture Tag", I'm able to choose between a few different projection methods for the material, for example, "Spherical" and "Cubic". This is useful for applying materials to meshes with no or problematic UV mapping. **How would I, for example, apply a "Spherical" or "Cubic" material projection to a mesh in Blender?***

[image]

*Also, **how do I tile/repeat a texture on a mesh?***

I do really appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Blender Render or Cycles Render? (This is shown at the top of the window.)

If you are using Blender, go to the "Textures" tab in properties, select "Projection" in the mapping tab, and change it to how you like. To tile it, change the size property.
[image: instrux1]

If you are using Cycles, open up Node Editing. Link the Image Texture to the Material, link the Mapping Vector to Image Vector, and link The Texture Coordinate to Mapping. (It makes more sense in an image.) Click "Flat" in the Image Texture, and select a projection. Change the "Scale" values in mapping to tile.
[image: instrux2]
[image: instrux3]